JOLT Multiply two values of other fields within a flattened array
Within a JSON I have a rope length with a metric value and my task is to generate a "twin" with imperial output. Depending on the unit of measure (uom) specified in the "metric" input, an imperial value should be calculated. The value after 'unit-' in the key is always variable.
This is my input JSON
{
  "unit-1012108-unitNo": "1012108",
  "unit-1012108-description": "IGNITE PROTON WIND",
  "unit-1012108-category": "211",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-identifier": "rope_length",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-type": "attribute",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-attributeDataType": "DECIMAL",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-values-0-value": "5.21",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-values-0-uom": "cm"
}

This is my desired Output JSON. The two auxiliary fields '-calc-' can be removed later.
The task of my Spec should be to calculate the 2.03 inch.
{
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-identifier" : "rope_length",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-type" : "attribute",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-values-0-uom" : "cm",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length-values-0-value" : "5.21",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length_imp-identifier" : "rope_length_imp",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length_imp-type" : "attribute",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-uom" : "inch",
  "unit-1012108-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-value" : "2.03",
  "unit-1012108-rope_length-calc_imp" : "0.39",
  "unit-1012108-rope_length_calc_metric" : "5.21"
}

I'm stuck on the spec. My questions are here. How can I multiply 'unit--rope_length-calc_imp' and 'unit--rope_length_calc_metric' and then assign the value to 'unit-*-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-value'? This is where I've gotten so far:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "unit-*-att-rope_length-values-0-value": [
        "&",
        "unit-&(0,1)-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-value",
        "unit-&(0,1)-rope_length_calc_metric"
      ],
      "unit-*-att-rope_length-values-0-uom": [
        "&",
        "unit-&(0,1)-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-uom"
      ],
      "unit-*-att-rope_length-identifier": [
        "&",
        "unit-&(0,1)-att-rope_length_imp-identifier"
      ],
      "unit-*-att-rope_length-type": [
        "&",
        "unit-&(0,1)-att-rope_length_imp-type"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "unit-*-att-rope_length_imp-identifier": "=concat(rope_length,'_imp')"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "unit-*-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-uom": {
        "m": {
          "#feet": "&2",
          "#3.28": "unit-&(2,1)-rope_length-calc_imp"
        },
        "cm": {
          "#inch": "&2",
          "#0.39": "unit-&(2,1)-rope_length-calc_imp"
        },
        "mm": {
          "#inch": "&2",
          "#0.04": "unit-&(2,1)-rope_length-calc_imp"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,&1)": "&2"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

There's no function for multiplication but can be simulated by using division functions such as
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "temp_val": "=divide(1,@(1,unit-1012108-att-rope_length-values-0-value))", 
      "unit-1012108-att-rope_length_imp-values_0-value": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,unit-1012108-rope_length-calc_imp),@(1,temp_val))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "temp_val": ""
    }
  }

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Thank you Barbaros. This is amazing. The divideAndRound - Function is very useful. One last question: Do you see a possibility to keep the 1012108 variable? Because it might happen, that the task to create an imperial twin appears several times in the input json. 1012108 might change. Unfortuantely this  "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,unit-&(0,1)-rope_length-calc_imp),@(1,temp_val))    does not work.

You're welcome  @KatjaBürger , can you please elaborate this new case added to the current question after writing Edit : 

Thank you very much for your help. I managed to solve the rest by grouping under the variable value, as you showed in your previous responses. Once again, thank you for your continued excellent support @Barbaros Özhan
